# Control line spacing in unordered list in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am creating a html report using R Markdown. The first paragraph contains a list of categories represented by certain samples with short descriptions. Here is an example:

```
This is the test list:

* **first group**:

    + **item 1** - this is the description of an item
    
* **second group**:

    + **item 2** - this is the description of an item
    
    + **item 3** - this is the description of an item
    
* **third group**:

    + **item 4** - this is the description of an item
    
* **fourth group**:

    + **item 5** - this is the description of an item
    
    + **item 6** - this is the description of an item
```

The text was inserted outside the code chunks. I would like to preserve this (even) spacing between the lines in knitted document, so it would be easy readable. Otherwise it looks too squished. Unfortunately R Markdown changes spacing, so some of them are uneven. I tried using trailing spaces and defining line breaks with br, but nothing changed. I could off course edit the html file manually after knitting, but this is a brute force way. R Markdown has to have some option to deal with it - but I was not able to figure it out myself. Would appreciate any help.

[image: enter this is how it looks like - the spacing is uneven]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `css` tag at the start of your rmarkdown document to specify how you would like the html output to interpret line heights:

````
```{css}
li {
  line-height: 3;
}
...
````

Comment: does this work the same for pdf?

Comment: This doesn't work for pdf